# How can I have rewrite rules with aliases?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, alias

I apologize in advance if this is too long.  I figure more detail is better than less and hope I'm not being horribly rambling :-)

I use WAMP on my laptop for local dev, and I have various `c:/wamp/alias/*` files each pointing to a project working directory.  I've had some excellent mod_rewrite help and gotten

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?ih(\/.*)?$ $1index.php$2 [L,QSA]
```

to work to change `localhost/.../ih/sub/dir` to `localhost/.../index.php/sub/dir` for URLs that are both SEO-friendly and short.  [I haven't gone on to do this in prod but I suspect it will work just as well.]  However, to get it all together I had to change my doc root from `c:/wamp/www/` to `c:/`, which I'd really rather not do just in case my Apache gets hacked and otherwise because it's a kludge.

My test alias file looks like

```
Alias /testme "c:/var/tmp/wamp-testme/"
<Directory "c:/var/tmp/wamp-testme/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?ih(\/.*)?$ $1index.php$2 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

and the error I get when trying to load `http://localhost/testme/rewrites/ih/sub/path` is

```
[Thu Jun 30 06:46:13 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]
  File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/var
```

with a matching

```
Not Found
The requested URL /var/tmp/wamp-testme/rewrites/index.php/sub/path
  was not found on this server.
```

in the browser.  Sure enough, the same config in my `c:/wamp/alias/flying.conf` file that points to the `c:/data/flying/` directory throws `File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/data` in the error log file, and so on.

Sooooo...  How can I have a rewrite rule that transcends aliases without having my doc root at my machine root dir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Odd: try adding a `PT` flag to the rewrite rule: this forces the re-written URL to be sent back to the URL mapping engine.

EDIT: try setting the `RewriteBase` on the Directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Trying again with my rewrite rule as `RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?ih(\/.*)?$ $1index.php$2 [L,QSA,PT]` still gives me the same error :-(

Comment: Hmm. You could try adding a RewriteBase: honestly not sure how that interacts with the Alias directive, but the 404 error could be because it is assuming the rewritten URL is relative to your apache root.

Comment: Looks like that was it!  Setting the base to `/testme/` for the case above did the trick.  Yay!  I tried putting the rules in the `httpd.conf` file, but whether with `RewriteBase "/"` there or `RewriteBase "/testme/"` in the alias file it didn't work, so I'm stuck with rules in every alias file.  Now I don't know if I need to next get this working via `.htaccess` files so that I don't have to keep messing with `httpd.conf` on my production server or ... won't have all of this complexity because I don't have aliases there :-)  [I do have vhosts, though.  More experimeting...]  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, yeah -- Femi, if you'll come back and add a 2nd answer to specify `Base` I'll happily check it as Correct for your reputation.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just edited the answer: no need to shower the question with multiple answers.

Comment: Femi: RewriteBase fixed this for me! I actually used it in a <Location /same-as-alias> tag under where I specify the Alias (but not in the .htaccess).